# Python problem with resize animate GIF

Tags: python, animation, python-imaging-library, gif

I'm want to resize animated GIF with save animate. I'm try use PIL and PythonMagickWand (ImageMagick) and with some GIF's get bad frame. When I'm use PIL, it mar frame in read frame. For test, I'm use this code:

```
from PIL import Image  
im = Image.open('d:/box_opens_closes.gif')
im.seek(im.tell()+1)
im.seek(im.tell()+1)
im.seek(im.tell()+1)
im.show()
```

When I'm use MagickWand with this code:

```
wand = NewMagickWand()
MagickReadImage(wand, 'd:/Box_opens_closes.gif')
MagickSetLastIterator(wand)
length = MagickGetIteratorIndex(wand)
MagickSetFirstIterator(wand)
for i in range(0, length+1):
    MagickSetIteratorIndex(wand,i)
    MagickScaleImage(wand, 87, 58)  
MagickWriteImages(wand, 'path', 1)
```

My GIF where I'm get bad frame this: [test gif](http://4gifs.com/gallery/d/154562-1/Box_opens_closes.gif)

In GIF editor software, all frames are ok. Where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: What does the bad frame look like?

Comment: Sample of bad result: http://i46.tinypic.com/4qgdx5.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm complete this. Must use:

```
wand2 = MagickCoalesceImages(wand)
MagickWriteImages(wand2, 'save_path', 1)
```