# Resizing GIFs with Wand + ImageMagick

Tags: python, image-processing, animated-gif

I am using [Wand 0.3.7](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.7/) with [ImageMagick 6.8.8-10](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to batch-resize some animated GIF files I have. But for some reason, Wand only resizes one frame in the image, leaving the others at their original size.

Here is the original image I am trying to resize:

[image: Original image]

And here is the output from Wand:

[image: Resized with Wand]

If I use ImageMagick from the command line directly (following instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257831/how-can-i-resize-an-animated-gif-file-using-imagemagick)), the GIF is correctly resized, as expected:

[image: Resized with ImageMagick]

This is how I am currently resizing the image:

```
with Image(filename="src.gif") as img:
    img.resize(50, 50)
    img.save("dest.gif")
```

I have also tried iterating through each frame and resizing them individually:

```
with Image(filename="src.gif") as img:
    for frame in img.sequence:
        frame.resize(50, 50)
        frame.destroy()
    img.save("dest.gif")
```

Both produce the same result seen above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896031/python-problem-with-resize-animate-gif

Answer (score 0):

You might try opening a new target `Image` and loop every frame into that:

```
with Image() as dst_image:
    with Image(filename=src_path) as src_image:
        for frame in src_image.sequence:
            frame.resize(x, y)
            dst_image.sequence.append(frame)
    dst_image.save(filename=dst_path)
```

works for me.